# Can zappa be used to run functions directly (non wsgi apps)

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda

zappa can easily be used to run flask apps. But it creates just one lambda function per app. Can I have a separate lambda function for each python function I declare?

Comment: I'm also looking for a way to deploy non-WSGI functions in Lambda using Zappa, but couldn't find a way to make it work so far. The two answers below didn't help. Have you found a way to solve this?

Answer (score 14):

Since this is the first SO result that you get when searching for *zappa for non-wsgi* I'll share my 2 cents.

If you just want use Zappa to deploy to AWS Lambda and be able to invoke your function **without** actually using WSGI you can do something like this:

#### myapp.py

```py
def foo(event, context):
    print('foo bar')
    return 'lambda triggered!'
```

#### zappa_settings.json

```json
{
    "dev": {
        "lambda_handler": "myapp.foo",
        ...
    }
}
```

Now go to your AWS Lambda console in browser and click *Test* and see the function being triggered.

Comment: It doesn't work for me. When I test the function in the AWS Console, it runs normally, without errors, but just returns null, not what's expected from 
`return ...`

Comment: btw. could you please try from your command line `zappa invoke dev 'myapp.foo'` (use your function here of course)?

Comment: I was able to trigger the function using this method but couldn't make it return content to the browser in the response, it just returned null. I looked into creating a mini wsgi app but that got complicated so I went with bottle instead which was easy. I would still love to know how to make it work because fewer dependencies is always nice.

Comment: @mislavcimpersak could you share a link to the documentation that covers this?

Comment: well, it's not strictly in the docs, it was more of a try-and-error approach that got me to this.

Answer (score 5):

You can create 'command' trigger events like below and zappa will invoke your python function:

```
{ 
  "command": "mymodule.myfunction"
}
```

Your app doesn't have to be a wsgi app. You can create each lambda function individually & upload the same zappa package as zip on each of them.

Comment: Can you please link to source or documentation where this trigger is documented?

Comment: @kilokahn [Here](https://github.com/Miserlou/Zappa/blob/e23339e5b25fd05daf52383fdef8eba83562c902/zappa/handler.py#L347) is the source.