# Zappa Python 3.6 Lambda Function without API Gateway

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda, zappa

I'm trying to deploy and test an AWS Lambda function I'm working on and have tried both [Zappa](https://github.com/Miserlou/Zappa) and [nficano's Python-Lambda](https://github.com/nficano/python-lambda).

**Zappa using @Task**

The problem arises when I trigger an asynchronous function using Zappa's @Task decorator - the task times out in 30s for some reason (that it is called from a Zappa/Flask/Python AWS function invoked via API Gateway may have something to do with it) and using @Task(remote_aws_lambda_function_name='function_name', remote_aws_region='ap-southeast-1') causes the output to freeze and the (unmodified) function to not work at all - I don't even get debug output in zappa tail!

**Python-Lambda**

While I am able to invoke and test my lambda locally with Python-Lambda, my code doesn't work on deployment, and I miss Zappa's advanced functionality, like 'zappa tail' that allows me to view the logs easily and check my (numerous) debug statements. Currently I have to log into CloudWatch and try to find the log entries (I can't!) and figure out how to fix whatever bug is in the code.

**Standalone Zappa**

I tried using Zappa to deploy the code directly as a separate Lambda function but I have no clue how to deploy a non-WSGI function using Zappa - as soon as I deploy, I invoke tail to see the function executing without any input and bumming out  :P

The logs are as follows:

```
(reviv) guha@katana:~/code/virtenvs/aws/connect$ zappa tail --since 1m
Calling tail for stage dev..
[1516065836740] Instancing..
[1516065838128] [DEBUG] 2018-01-16T01:23:58.128Z ebb7aba4-fa5b-11e7-ac3c-0f9b2ef3a86e Zappa Event: {'time': '2018-01-16T01:23:55Z', 'detail-type': 'Scheduled Event', 'source': 'aws.events', 'account': '985048216164', 'region': 'ap-southeast-1', 'detail': {}, 'version': '0', 'resources': ['arn:aws:events:ap-southeast-1:99487679w65e7r99t:rule/connect-dev-zappa-keep-warm-handler.keep_warm_callback'], 'id': 'dc1fdc11-20d9-bd1a-6234-f040721e38be', 'kwargs': {}}
[1516065838144] [DEBUG] 2018-01-16T01:23:58.128Z ebb7aba4-fa5b-11e7-ac3c-0f9b2ef3a86e Zappa Event: {}
[1516065854137] Instancing..
[1516065855525] [DEBUG] 2018-01-16T01:24:15.525Z f61ef035-fa5b-11e7-8303-85b30872657c Zappa Event: {'resource': '/', 'path': '/', 'httpMethod': 'GET', 'headers': {'Accept': '*/*', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'CloudFront-Forwarded-Proto': 'https', 'CloudFront-Is-Desktop-Viewer': 'true', 'CloudFront-Is-Mobile-Viewer': 'false', 'CloudFront-Is-SmartTV-Viewer': 'false', 'CloudFront-Is-Tablet-Viewer': 'false', 'CloudFront-Viewer-Country': 'IN', 'Host': '7yushhfjij.execute-api.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com', 'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.18.4', 'Via': '1.1 68748abc6b5ec82c2a55779d81161060.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)', 'X-Amz-Cf-Id': 'kwDMBT196jKFPNVxn5pbFGArBmuV3p3PqyqAVT2DA8CZYlP33f__fg==', 'X-Amzn-Trace-Id': 'Root=1-5a5d543d-1545839e757e3c8677ffd744', 'X-Forwarded-For': '183.82.183.1, 54.182.245.89', 'X-Forwarded-Port': '443', 'X-Forwarded-Proto': 'https'}, 'queryStringParameters': None, 'pathParameters': None, 'stageVariables': None, 'requestContext': {'requestTime': '16/Jan/2018:01:24:13 +0000', 'path': '/dev', 'accountId': '985048216164', 'protocol': 'HTTP/1.1', 'resourceId': 'kr649sck98', 'stage': 'dev', 'requestTimeEpoch': 1516065853577, 'requestId': 'f6172848-fa5b-11e7-a3bb-e1fb97441a2c', 'identity': {'cognitoIdentityPoolId': None, 'accountId': None, 'cognitoIdentityId': None, 'caller': None, 'sourceIp': '183.82.183.1', 'accessKey': None, 'cognitoAuthenticationType': None, 'cognitoAuthenticationProvider': None, 'userArn': None, 'userAgent': 'python-requests/2.18.4', 'user': None}, 'resourcePath': '/', 'httpMethod': 'GET', 'apiId': '7yushhfjij'}, 'body': None, 'isBase64Encoded': False}
[1516065855548] Entering : reviv_assign_responder
[1516065855548] #################################
[1516065855548] Calling find_closest_responder in 20
[1516065855549] find_closest_responder : 0
[1516065856550] find_closest_responder : 1
[1516065857551] find_closest_responder : 2
[1516065858552] find_closest_responder : 3
[1516065859553] find_closest_responder : 4
[1516065860554] find_closest_responder : 5
[1516065861555] find_closest_responder : 6
[1516065862556] find_closest_responder : 7
[1516065863557] find_closest_responder : 8
[1516065864558] find_closest_responder : 9
[1516065865559] find_closest_responder : 10
[1516065866561] find_closest_responder : 11
[1516065867562] find_closest_responder : 12
[1516065868563] find_closest_responder : 13
[1516065869564] find_closest_responder : 14
[1516065870565] find_closest_responder : 15
[1516065871566] find_closest_responder : 16
[1516065872567] find_closest_responder : 17
[1516065873569] find_closest_responder : 18
[1516065874570] find_closest_responder : 19
[1516065875571] Entering : find_closest_responder
[1516065877568] find_closest_responder : we have a responder!
[1516065877817] Find closest responder called
[1516065877817] Calling wait_one_and_notify in 5
[1516065877817] reviv_assign_responder : 0
[1516065878819] reviv_assign_responder : 1
[1516065879820] reviv_assign_responder : 2
[1516065880821] reviv_assign_responder : 3
[1516065881822] reviv_assign_responder : 4
[1516065882823] Entering : wait_one_and_notify
[1516065883070] incidentid : 09e77bfea119937eee67c2e3d90541ff
[1516065883070] wait_one_and_notify : incident record exists
[1516065883070] wait_one_and_notify : We have a responder : Updating the requester
[1516065883073] [DEBUG] 2018-01-16T01:24:43.73Z f61ef035-fa5b-11e7-8303-85b30872657c Starting new HTTPS connection (1): fcm.googleapis.com
[1516065883479] [DEBUG] 2018-01-16T01:24:43.478Z f61ef035-fa5b-11e7-8303-85b30872657c https://fcm.googleapis.com:443 "POST /fcm/send HTTP/1.1" 200 None
[1516065883484] Success message sent to requester
[1516065883484] wait_one_and_notify : We have a responder : Updating the responder
[1516065883484] [DEBUG] 2018-01-16T01:24:43.482Z f61ef035-fa5b-11e7-8303-85b30872657c Starting new HTTPS connection (1): fcm.googleapis.com
[1516065883853] [DEBUG] 2018-01-16T01:24:43.853Z f61ef035-fa5b-11e7-8303-85b30872657c https://fcm.googleapis.com:443 "POST /fcm/send HTTP/1.1" 200 None
[1516065883854] Notifying those not selected
[1516065883854] Entering : notify_non_selected
[1516065884101] Count of participants : 1
[1516065884101] Count of non-participants : 0
[1516065884101] notify_non_selected : no one to notify
[1516065884101] 'NoneType' object is not iterable
[1516066076720] [DEBUG] 2018-01-16T01:27:56.720Z 7b0e28f0-fa5c-11e7-a1f9-8945479469b0 Zappa Event: {'time': '2018-01-16T01:27:55Z', 'detail-type': 'Scheduled Event', 'source': 'aws.events', 'account': '985048216164', 'region': 'ap-southeast-1', 'detail': {}, 'version': '0', 'resources': ['arn:aws:events:ap-southeast-1:985048216164:rule/connect-dev-zappa-keep-warm-handler.keep_warm_callback'], 'id': 'd713f870-29a1-5c7b-329c-0fa1aeeb09c1', 'kwargs': {}}
[1516066076721] [DEBUG] 2018-01-16T01:27:56.720Z 7b0e28f0-fa5c-11e7-a1f9-8945479469b0 Zappa Event: {}
^C
```

[This is a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44730610/can-zappa-be-used-to-run-functions-directly-non-wsgi-apps), [as is this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43779871/call-aws-lambda-function-without-using-api-gateway-and-ec2-instance) but both don't solve my problem as I don't seem to be doing something obviously wrong.

How do I get my function to work?

[EDIT/UPDATE]: @kevin-christopher-henry asked if i'd tried using @task_sns as an invocation method, and I have. Unfortunately, I get an error message about Parameter Validation failing similar to the one in [the bug report filed on this issue](https://github.com/Miserlou/Zappa/issues/1323).

(this is from the report - I lost the message when I closed my terminal :P )

```
 Parameter validation failed:
    Invalid type for parameter Message, value: b'{"task_path": "my_async_task", "capture_response": false, "response_id": null, "args": [{"a": 4, "b": 10}], "kwargs": {}, "command": "zappa.async.route_sns_task"}', type: <class 'bytes'>, valid types: <class 'str'>: ParamValidationError
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    ...
```

Comment: Regarding the Zappa solution, it looks like the task has inherited the [30 second API Gateway restriction](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/limits.html#api-gateway-limits). Perhaps that's due to the default direct Lambda invocation. Have you tried [`task_sns`](https://github.com/Miserlou/Zappa#task-sources)?

Comment: Hi Kevin, yes I have tried @task_sns as well, but I get an error about Parameter validation failing - there is an open bug report out on this as well at https://github.com/Miserlou/Zappa/issues/1323. Adding the error messafge in an edit to my question as well :)

Comment: @KevinChristopherHenry is there any way to un-inherit the 30 second API Gateway restriction?

Comment: I don't know, I wouldn't have expected that timeout to be there at all. I'd certainly expect the SNS version to avoid it. There is a [simple fix](https://github.com/Miserlou/Zappa/pull/1331/files) to that Zappa bug, so you could apply it yourself and try again.

Comment: Update : This issue is still not fixed in Zappa as on 08 Feb 17.

https://github.com/Miserlou/Zappa/issues/1323

Comment: It would help if you had some code, zappa settings perhaps
Is this something you have defined?
`"timeout_seconds": 30, // Maximum lifespan for the Lambda function (default 30, max 300.)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are using **@task** decorator with zappa, the new lambda instance is created with the same configuration of the father (the caller), by default the **"timeout_seconds"** is 30 in the *`zappa_settings`*

> "timeout_seconds": 30, // Maximum lifespan for the Lambda function
>   (default 30, max 300.)

Take a look at the [doc](https://github.com/Miserlou/Zappa#advanced-settings).

So, you probably need to change this value.

Comment: I tried changing this but the function still times out at 30s. Any idea why?

Comment: "dev": {
        "app_function": "application.application",
        "aws_region": "ap-southeast-1",
        "profile_name": "default",
        "project_name": "aws",
        "runtime": "python3.6",
        "s3_bucket": "zappa-xxxxxx",
        "route53_enabled" : "false",
        "domain" : "masked",
 "timeout_seconds": 300,
 "certificate_arn" : "arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:xxxxxxxxxxx:certificate/xxx-xxx-ccc-xxx-xxxxxxx"
    }
}

Comment: @kilokahn can you share some of your function?